# Cant authenticate user silently with ADAL for Office 365 REST API on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, office365, adal, office365api

So I'm trying to implement persistent tokens for our office authentication so that the user does not have to sign into office each time they are in a new session. The code I currently have to authenticating the user is as below.

```
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
var tokenCache = new ADALTokenCache(User.Identity.GetUserId());
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, tokenCache );
var token = authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, clientId, new UserIdentifier(userId, UserIdentifierType.RequiredDisplayableId));
```

But everything I've tried so far gives me the error below
[image]

The Exception is: `"Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken"`

The method Im using to aquire the token in the first place is as below

```
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
var fileCache = new ADALTokenCache(User.Identity.GetUserId());
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, fileCache);
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                authCode, redirectUri, credential, scopes);
```

And the token cache im using is a db implementation which I made from a tutorial which I cannnot find again, if I watch the db I can see that new tokens are being inserted into the db when `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` is called.

Update:
This is my result from authResult when calling `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync`
[image]

I have marked Virbonet's answer as the solution but I have not fixed it but he did explain to me where I was going wrong

Comment: Where do you get the authCode from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AcquireTokenSilent` cannot work if you are passing /common in the authority. Using "common" is equivalent to declaring that you don' know what tenant is the user from, hence ADAL cannot return a cached token form a specific tenant - user interaction is required to determine which tenant should be used. 
If you want to call `AcquireTokenSilent` you need to initialize the authority with the exact tenant of the incoming user, as in `"https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+tenantID` here `tenantID` is the tenantID from the current `ClaimsPrincipal`.

Comment: Ahhh that makes so much sense, thank you. Going through the tutorials I never saw that mentioned. However I am still at a bit of a loss as to where i'd get the current users tennantID from, would you be able where I could get it from or some resource on the matter?

Comment: Try string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;

Comment: That doesn't appear to be working, if it helps I am using an almost out of the box ASP.NET Identity 2 Auth and don't set the users TennantID anywhere, does the Office 365 API provide it somewhere that i'd need to assign it to the current User maybe?

Comment: If you didn't sign in with azure ad and used aspnet identity instead, you must remember the tenantid in your own code. You should find it in the authenticationresult from your first call to acquiretokenbyauthorizationtoken

Comment: Ahh that makes sense thanks, however when I call `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` the tennantID returned is null. I've updated my post with a SS of the returned auth result

Comment: Argh, you are using ADAL experimental... That really isn't supported :( what scopes are you passing in your first request and everywhere else?

Comment: Oh bugger, [This](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/dotnet) was the tutorial I used to get it working in the first place. Anyway the only scope we use is `https://outlook.office.com/calendars.readwrite` . Should I change to non experimental?

Comment: are you getting tokens for organizational accounts, or for MSAs (former Live DI)? The non experimental ADAL cannot work with MSAs

Comment: Im not certain but I think a few Users will be using organisational accounts but no MSAs as far as I understand

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you said for those accounts. In reply to that, no they aren't Oragnisational or MSA accounts, just local to the App

Comment: For the API access authorization flow you can't use locals, office expects org or MSA accounts

Comment: Wait, sorry the calendar accounts that users will be signing into the api with will mostly be organisation accounts. I think I misunderstood you for a minute there

Comment: @vibronet, seems like AcquireTokenSilentAsync should include the initial advice in its exception if the authority is "common".

Comment: @vibronet Hey, so I've come back to this problem after giving it a break for a bit if you don't mind giving me some assistance with it. I realized that I can retrieve the tenant Id from the JWT token passed by ADAL which I have then used to retrieve the token silently with the authority `https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTID/oauth2/authorize` aswell as `.../TENANTID/v2.0` yet they all give the same error as before

Comment: There might be other mismatches: maybe you save the token in a cache initialized with a certain user ID, but when you go to retrieve it afterwards you use a different value. Or you now have multiple tokens for different users, hence if you ask for a token w/o disambiguating which user you want the call will fail. Note, the ADAL you are using is experimental/unsupported. If you are working on a production app , you should consider using the stable version of ADAL. If you need both MSA and org users, for now you might need to work at the protocol level in order to obtain production ready code.

Comment: Also note, I am heads down for //build hence I won't be very responsive for the next 10 days or so. Apologies!

Comment: @vibronet That's fair enough, thanks for the help anyway. I did try using the 2.23 stable version but kept getting something along the lines of incompatible versions. However I think it would be best to try going about this again. Is the Outlook 365 Rest Api v2.0 not compatible with ADAL 2.23? Also would you know of any resources/examples for doing this on a asp.net app?

Answer (score 0):

This is the function call you need to use: **AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode()** but not **AcquireTokenSilent()**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the call to AcquireTokenSilent is correct, given that Toxicable already got the token via code previously - but his authority settings cannot be used with AcquireTokenSilent  as I detailed in my answer.